# Constants in Objective-C and "duplicate symbol" linker error

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker, duplicates, constants

I've declared a constant with the same name in some different classes, in their `.m` file, this way:

```
@implementation MyViewController
const NSInteger numberOfItems = 6;
...
@end
```

But I get a "duplicate symbol" error when trying to build the project. I've found several posts dealing with this issue regarding extern or global constants, but what I'd want is just declaring some constants private to their class, how can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: I don't believe you can declare a constant private to the class, but as @MichK answers, you can give your const the `static` keyword to keep it private to that source file (which achieves your goal if only that class is in the source file).

Answer (score 32):

If you want to use constant only in one `.m` file then declare it as `static`.
For example:`static NSString * const CONSTANT_STRING = @"Constant I am"`.

In case of `NSInteger` you can write in your every `.m` file:

```
static const NSInteger my_const = 3;
```

If you want globals (one constant with one value visible in every file) then write in your `.h`:

```
extern const NSInteger my_global_const;
```

and in your `.m` file you can add

```
const NSInteger my_global_const = 5;
```

Comment: `static NSString * const CONSTANT_STRING = @"For the win!"` @MichK